# Java Memoization Recursive Method

Tags: java, memoization

Been trying to figure out this issue for a while but can't get my head around it.

Question: Given the method below. Optimise it with memoization.

```
public static long cat(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += cat(i) * cat(n - i - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I have tried:

```
private static int memCat(int n, int[] cache) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int result = 0;

    if (cache[n] == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += memCat(i, cache) * memCat(n - i - 1, cache);
        }
        cache[n] = result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

My idea behind this is that as the result for all the counts in the inner for loop will be saved. So it does not have to be repeated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(cat(5)); //Prints 42
    System.out.println(memCat(5, new int[5 + 1])); //Prints 1 
}
```

My eyes and brain are tired so it may just be a simple mistake.

Comment: I realize you are most likely doing this for a class, but for anyone else who comes along let me suggest you think VERY CAREFULLY before doing this, and probably just don't.  Java can and will do this type of optimization for you if it thinks it's a good idea. You are unlikely to speed it up more than you slow it down with techniques like this. NEVER optimize until you are failing to meet a requirement, and then measure before & after before proceeding with an optimization like this(and even if you do see an improvement, it's likely to behave differently in the next JRE version, so retest)

Comment: So explicitly implementing tail recursion/memoization/tabulation can be worse in terms of performance ?

Comment: It will be worse if your VM already does it for you. It's not always bad of course, but that kind of optimization really has to be tested in the real world in every situation you want to use it in (not micro-benchmark tests) to be sure that they are actually valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you prepare `cache[]`, but you never use it. Here is the fix, it's rather straightforward:

```
int result = cache[n];
if (result == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += memCat(i, cache) * memCat(n - i - 1, cache);
    }
    cache[n] = result;
}
```

Now the value of `cache` is returned when it has been computed before, because `result` is assigned a value of `cache[n]` before entering the conditional.